# How to increment a cell references in a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

Say I have numbers in cells A1 to Z1 and in cell A2, I have the formula A1 + B1. What method can I use so that in Cell B2 all my cell references are incremented by 2 so that the formula is C1 + D1? Assume I have to repeat this up to Z1. The method should also preserve absolute references, so if I have absolute references and relative references only the relative references should change.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can give you a "generic" way... which is a very "low-tech" way of doing it, but assuming you can propagate your formulas to the right so that the correct formulas exist, just not in the right places, it solves things. And if you need to then copy the finished product somewhere, it will maintain all the same relationships.

So, you have `=A1+B1` in cell A2. You copy it to B2, C2, D2... Y2. Now B2 has `=B1+C1` (not wanted), C2 has `=C1+D1` (wanted, but not in the right place), and so on over to Y2 which has the desired `=Y1+Z1` but is about 12-13 columns right of where you want it.

Not a lot of progress it would seem.

But next, select (highlight) all the undesired cells. Basically, highlight B2, D2, F2, H2, and so on over to X2. Delete the cells (the cells, not just their contents) and when Excel asks, tell it to shift the kept cells left.

Now you have all those "wanted but..." cells only, and they are also in the right places.

This handles any absolute references in their formulas with no problem. Not saying you were able to just copy the A2 cell and paste into the B2:X2 range without adjusting them, as you might have some changing absolute references and it might all be mysteriously complex, but if it was just a matter of mentioning that so that formulaic solutions honored them with them being straightforward, this does the job, no problem.

The layout you describe likely is not something to be copied and pasted in bulk somewhere else as it just isn't conducive to that (so not like a lot of problems where you'd want to copy and paste down a few thousand rows), but if you want the same structure elsewhere, just copy the final resulting cells in row 2 to be the new "row 2" wherever else it is needed.

Again, so absolutely low-tech. Almost embarrassing one might say. But easy and hard to mess up. Not complex like any formulaic method would be.

And if one worries about it (not really any problem nowadays unless one has 100,000 rows of something... computers are very capable now), there's nothing "volatile" in this.

If you have 300 columns, not just 26, it just takes an extra half-minute. Not really a beast in terms of effort.

For a non-volatile method, you can just use an `INDEX` function in each cell, specifying the two columns to take for each calculation. You'd use `COLUMN()` to get the column the result goes in, multiplies by two and subtracts one for one addend, then the same but not subtracting one for the second addend. That could be copied and pasted over. Might look like:

```
=INDEX($A1:$Z1,1,COLUMN()*2-1) + INDEX($A1:$Z1,1,COLUMN()*2)
```

When looking at B2, what would be happening would be that for the first half, Excel finds `COLUMN()` is "2", so it multiplies by 2 to get 4 and subtracts one to get 3 giving the cell C1 to add, and in the second half stops at 4 to give cell D1. And adds them. Cell C2 gives "3" for column, so elements 5 and 6 (E1, F1) are returned from the A1:Z1 array/range.

More computationally heavy than the simple A1+B1 formulas the low-tech method gives you, but for 13 formulas? Meaningless.

Caveats? Well, it would not handle those absolute references, but you can hand type those once, in A2, and use the above for the finding of the two headline cells. Low-tech in its own way!

Either way though, low-tech is something to remember when wanting to do things Excel is not immediately suited to do.

Answer (score 1):

One of many possible options is the formula

`=SUM(OFFSET($A$1;0;(COLUMN()-1)*2;1;2))`

[image: Demo result]

Comment: Another variant of the `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1;(COLUMN()-1)*2+1;4;1))+INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1;(COLUMN()-1)*2+2;4;1))` type is possible, but I don’t like it because of its length; it is difficult to read, understand and correct.

Comment: Is there anything more generic that you could apply to more complex formulas?